# Do shorter JSON keys make smaller NoSQL documents?

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I've been confused about this for a while. Rethinkdb is schema-less, so with the way it stores information (or any other NoSQL database's method of storage), would a smaller JSON key make shorter documents?

```
 {"avg": 312} vs {"average": 312}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now yes since RethinkDB doesn't compress fields.
See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1396